# How to access DOM element before showing or loading QWebView?

Tags: c++, qt, dom, qtwebkit

I am using [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html) to display html in my app. I set html by using [QWebView::setHtml()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html#setHtml) function.

Problem is that accessing DOM before `loadFinished` does not work. But after `loadFinished` it works. So I guess DOM is available only after loading. I want to check DOM content just after `setHtml()` but before `show()`.

Is it Possible? If possible what is the way to access DOM before calling `show()` on `QWebView`. There is no function in docs like `startLoad()`.

I am using Qt 4.8 on Windows 8.

Comment: No comments / answers yet. Is question clear or  need more information. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

In the constructor:

```
{
    // ...
    webView->setHtml( /* ... */ );

    connect( webView, SIGNAL( loadFinished( bool ) ),
             this,    SLOT( onLoadFinished( bool ) ) );
    // ...
}
```

In the slot:

```
void onLoadFinished( bool )
{
    // Check what you want.
    // ...

    // Show after you finished your work.
    webView->show();
}
```